# Getting urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] Error

Tags: python, urllib2

I try desperately to solve my Python 2.7 coding issue to get some line run :

```
RPC_URL     = "http://127.0.0.1:8332"
rpc_id = random.getrandbits(32)
callstr = json.dumps({"id": rpc_id, "method": method, "params": params})
authstr = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (RPC_USER, RPC_PASS)).strip()

request = urllib2.Request(RPC_URL)
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % authstr)
request.add_data(callstr)

f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response = json.loads(f.read())
```

But I'm getting `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] Error`

I believe must be the proxy somehow and test several things, also stated in here with no success.

Any advice what I can do ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A quick search for `errno 10061` suggests the service you're trying to connect to isn't running; is your RPC server on port 8332 actually up when you try this?

Comment: yes, up and running. I have seen in other posts that the proxy causes the problem, but cannot fix it myself.

Comment: Can you post anything about your proxy configuration, then?

Comment: I guess its a software mistake of the server, need to investigate a bit more.